# Where are weights stored in online applications?

Tags: database, web, machine-learning, storage

I'm new to web development, so please excuse me if this question is trivial.

I have a background in machine learning, and am currently working on an application that involves various uses of machine learning techniques. When one is writing such an application, where are feature weights normally stored? The idea is that as users add data, the model will update feature weights to better learn the data.

Does one normally store feature weights in a database? How does one normally deal with this scenario? For example, suppose that I have a trained model and want to evaluate for a certain input. If feature weights are stored in a database, that requires looking up possibly several different values, which seems very computationally expensive.

What are the best practices for managing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really depend on a specific case and environment. If performance matters, you would probably want keep them in memory and store in the database or file only for the means of keeping them permanently.

When loading the application, it would be best to load the full model into memory. This might or might not be possible, based on the available resources and the amount of data. If your model is too large, you could pre-load the needed parts as required.

You would need to make expensive I/O operations only on application load and when model changes (and even for the changes you can defer the write ops).

You can find similar discussion here:
[Neural Network / Machine Learning memory storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770832/neural-network-machine-learning-memory-storage)